# Django Rest Framework - Latest child per instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, one-to-many

Using Django Rest Framework, I'm building a web application that saves information on Products and its Prices. A Product can have multiple Prices over time. My models look like this:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='prices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

I've set up the following serializers:

```py
class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = ('price', 'date')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prices = PriceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'prices')
```

Now, I want to create an APIView that shows all products with their latest price. Like so:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Product A",
        "price_latest": 1.00
    },
    {
        "name": "Product B",
        "price_latest": 2.00
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) from DRF:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latest_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_latest_price(self, instance):
        price_obj = instances.prices.order_by('-date').first()
        if price_obj:
            return price_obj.price
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'latest_price')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! But it rises one problem: the serialization time is super slow in comparison to just serializing all prices. Even with prefetching.. any clue on how to speed it up?

Comment: prefetching was the way to go, however, when you're using `order_by`, the prefetch becomes "useless", since a new query with the ordering will be done to the database :(. basically every `QuerySet.order_by()` results in a new db call. - I have come across this though: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch and apparently by passing an ordered queryset to it you could get it to work. Something like: `Prefetch('prices', Price.objects.order_by('-date')`.